# Ratio of sum of squares of Normal Distributions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Find $$E[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{51} X_i^2}{\sum_{i=51}^{101} X_i^2}], $$if $X_1,X_2,...,X_{51}$ are independent and are distributed as N(0,1).
 This question appeared in my final exam of probability and stochastic processes, that occurred today .I couldn't answer this in the exam and would love to find out more. I did simplify this a bit though. Here's what I did:
$Y = \sum_{i=1}^{50} X_i^2$, $Z = \sum_{i=52}^{101} X_i^2,X = X_{51}$. Then, 
$X \sim \gamma(1/2,1/2), Y \sim \gamma(25,1/2), Z \sim\gamma(25,1/2). $ Then we wish to find $E[\frac{X+Y}{X+Z}]$, where X,Y,Z are independent random variables. I was stuck after this, as there was this integral of $$\frac{x^{-1/2}}{x+z}e^{-25x}, 0\leq x < \infty$$ Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean $X = X_{51}^2$, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the ratio as $\frac{Y}{X+Z} + \frac{X}{X+Z}$. Then $\frac{Y}{X+Z}$ has an [F-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution) with $d_1 = 50$ and $d_2 = 51$ degrees of freedom. And $\frac{X}{X+Z}$ has a [Beta-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) with parameters $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}, \beta = \frac{50}{2} = 25$ .

Comment: I do not know what a F-distribution is. We only covered basic distributions in class. (Geometric,Gamma, Normal,Cauchy,Beta- 1,Beta-2,etc.) Please elaborate on your answer by adding the required details, adding a complete description of this distribution and the proof of the expectation of F-distribution being equal to the formula given by you.

Comment: @bat_of_doom Done. The Wikipedia articles have more.

Comment: Thanks, the breakdown into the two distributions rings a bell.  That, the second one is beta is clear, we don't need the distribution of the ratio of two independent gamma rvs for evaluating the expectation of their ratio. The integral turns out to be pretty short.

Comment: @bat_of_doom You can split $E\left[\frac{Y}{X+Z}\right]$ as $E[Y]E\left[\frac{1}{X+Z}\right]$ and calculate the second one given $X+Z\sim \gamma(51/2, 1/2)$.

Comment: And also $E\left[\frac{X_{51}^2}{X_{51}^2+\ldots+X_{101}^2}\right]=\frac{1}{51}$ by symmetry: 
$$E\left[\frac{X_{51}^2}{X_{51}^2+\ldots+X_{101}^2}\right]=\ldots=E\left[\frac{X_{101}^2}{X_{51}^2+\ldots+X_{101}^2}\right]$$
and the sum of this expectations equals to $1$.

Comment: @NCh Wow, that's cool.